# How do you change the popup file with manifest 3?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have stated to build a chrome extensions and I ran across a problem with changing the popup file. I want to include a button that takes the user to another popup window that replaces the default one. In manifest versions 2 or less, you could do the following:

```
settingButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "blank.html"});
}, false);
```

What is the alternative for this in manifest 3?

Comment: `browserAction` is `action` in MV3, see the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: I tried adding the following:

settingButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      chrome.action.setPopup(blank.html);
}, false);

Nothing happens when you click the button.

Comment: This is invalid code because `blank.html` should be quoted. Also you didn't specify it using `popup` property like you did in the original code. You can debug your code in devtools. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. Also see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-setPopup).